What is the arohana and avarohana of sree-rāga?
What is the arohana and avarohana of sree-rāga according to this verse which is given below ?
षड्जे षाड्जीममुद्भूतं श्रीरागं स्वल्पपञ्चमम् । सन्यामांशग्रहं मन्द्रगान्धारं तारमध्यमम् ॥१५९॥ समशेषस्वरं वीरे शास्ति श्रीकरणाग्रणीः ।
